# Shimano ST-5500

Tags: shimano, brifters

I can't find any bracket cover for the Shimano ST-5500 for sale online, however i found someone on Shopee (philippine's ebay) selling a bracket cover for ST-5600.

Will a ST-5600 bracket cover fit in a ST-5500? (don't mind the glue residue on my bars lol)[image: st-5500]

Comment: Based on this [reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/bikewrench/comments/c2kzl9/shimano_105_5500_replacement_hood_options/) somebody is saying, Ultegra 6600 and 105 5700 (so x600/x700 series) won't work, so you might be out of luck with new these (or new parts in general). I think this makes sense because the covers are usually compatible across a generation, my LBS also sold me Ultegra-labeled ones for my R5700 - I'm not sure if they replacement parts are even groupset-specific.